# IText7 Throws FileNotFoundException on .NET 5

Tags: .net, .net-core, itext, itext7, .net-core-3.1

## **`IText7 Version : 7.1.14`**

We have detected that we cannot use IText7 in .NET 5 :

```
private byte[] BuildPDF()
{
   using(var stream = new MemoryStream())
   {
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(stream));
        Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);

        Table table = new Table(UnitValue.CreatePercentArray(8)).UseAllAvailableWidth();

        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
           table.AddCell("hi");
        }

       doc.Add(table);

       doc.Close();
   
       return stream.ToArray();
   }
}
```

This simple code is working on .NET Core 3.1 Project but does **NOT** work on .NET 5 project.

Thrown **`Exception`** as below:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions,
Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. 
The system cannot find the file specified.

iText.IO.Util.ResourceUtil.LoadITextResourceAssemblies()

TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'iText.IO.Util.ResourceUtil' threw an exception.

iText.IO.Font.Type1Parser.GetMetricsFile()
```

A .dll cannot found, but how to solve this or how to make a bug report to IText7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions/ (Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions) packet manually from on the above link or from Manage Nuget Packages on project solution.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to have been fixed in iText v7.1.17 - the dependency is now included in the NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7/7.1.17#dependencies-body-tab. No need to explicitly reference the dependency in caller assemblies.